# prestashop add combination internal server error

Tags: php, prestashop, combinations

I create a product and i try to assign combinations (color/size) to him.

But only first combination is added successfully! and then i receive an internal server error (500)

that's what i use:

```
$combination =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<prestashop>
    <combination>
        <id xmlns=""></id>
        <id_product xmlns="">'.$id.'</id_product>
        <quantity xmlns="">' . $quantity . '</quantity>
        <supplier_reference xmlns="">Inditex</supplier_reference>
        <price xmlns="">' . $price . '</price>
        <wholesale_price xmlns="">' . $price . '</wholesale_price>
        <minimal_quantity xmlns="">1</minimal_quantity>
        <default_on xmlns="">1</default_on>

        <associations xmlns="">
            <product_option_values xmlns="">
                <product_option_value><id>'.$color_id.'</id></product_option_value>
                <product_option_value><id>'.$size_id.'</id></product_option_value>
            </product_option_values>
        </associations>
    </combination>
</prestashop>';
$response = curlCall($url . '/api/combinations/products/'.$id, $combination, 'POST', $api_key);
$load_string = simplexml_load_string($response);
$combination_id = $load_string->combination->id;
```

That code is working fine only if the product has no combinations.
(color_id and size_id are verified and i don't use same id's)

save me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an other method and that's work fine :

```
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $api_key, FALSE);
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => $url .'/api/combinations?schema=blank'));

$resources = $xml->children()->children();

$resources->id_product          = $ps_product_id;
$resources->wholesale_price     = $wholesale_price;
$resources->price               = $price;
$resources->unit_price_impact   = $unit_price_impact;
$resources->minimal_quantity    = $minimal_quantity;
$resources->quantity            = $quantity;
$resources->weight              = $weight;

$resources->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value[0]->id = $color_id;
$resources->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value[1]->id = $size_id;

$request = $xml->asXML();

//This is a function that curl request to specific URL using method (POST)
$response = ps_curl($url . '/api/combinations', $request, 'POST', $api_key);

$xml_load  = simplexml_load_string($response);
$id        = $xml_load->combination->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For other people reading this question, the change in method is not the solution. The problem is the url you used.

The first and second method is the same, only different methods to build the xml, the only difference is the url:

- $url.'/api/combinations/products/'.$id

Vs.

- $url.'/api/combinations

First url don't call a valid resource in the Prestashop web services.
I suggest using the library https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php to help prevent this situation.